# Removing dynamically created row from array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have two textboxes and an add button. When you click add it generates a table below the textboxes with each row having a Remove button. When you click remove it removes the table row but doesn't remove the contents from within the array (at least i don't think).

How do I get it to remove the contents as well? Currently when I click add and then remove a few it messes up my database table by inserting the first one fine but then messing up the rest by either not inserting it, or just adding 1 column.... If i don't remove any it works perfectly fine.

```
 var $tdRemoveRow = $('<td>').appendTo($tr);
    $('<a>').attr({
        'href': '#',
    'id': 'submit-button'
    }).text("Remove").click(function() {
        $tr.remove();
        return false;
    }).appendTo($tdRemoveRow);
```

The error must be in the above code somewhere. Does anyone see an issue?

```
 var locations = [];   
$("#add").click(function() {
    var address = $("#address").val();
    var city = $("#city").val();

    if (address =="" || city =="") {
    $("#locationDeals").text('*Please enter an address and city');
    return false;
} 
else {
codeAddress();
        var $tr = $('<tr>').css({
            'padding': '4px',
            'background-color': '#ddd'
        }).appendTo('#locationDeals');

        var location = [
            address,
            city                
        ];
        locations.push(location);

        for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            var $td = $('<td>').appendTo($tr);
            $('<span>').text(location[i]).appendTo($td);
            $('<input type="hidden">').attr({
                'name': 'loc[' + ctr + '][' + i + ']',
                'value': location[i]
            }).appendTo($td);
        }

        var $tdRemoveRow = $('<td>').appendTo($tr);
        $('<a>').attr({
            'href': '#',
        'id': 'submit-button'
        }).text("Remove").click(function() {
            $tr.remove();
            return false;
        }).appendTo($tdRemoveRow);

        ctr++;

        $("#locationtext").text('');
        return false;
    } 
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When removing the row, use `.splice` to also remove it from the array:

```
.click(function() {
    $tr.remove();
    locations.splice(locations.indexOf(location), 1);
    return false;
})
```

Note that this will not behave correctly if `location` is not inside `locations`, but with your code this is guaranteed not to be the case.

---

You shuold decrement the indices in the input names as well (just before removing the `tr`):

```
var index = $tr.index();
$("#tableDailyDeals input[type='hidden']").each(function() {
    this.name = this.name.replace(/\[(\d+)\]/, function(str, number) {
      return "[" + (+number > index ? number - 1 : number) + "]";
    });
});
```

Comment: http://eurothermwindows.com/ed/inputform.php try it out yourself. i modified the code to your fix. it currently just appends all the results into 1 column on the table generated. look at the daily deals where it asks for special day, name, etc.

Comment: also, the mysql database yields similar results when i remove the row from the generated html table

Comment: @pimvb worth mentioning that `indexOf` is not available in all browsers

Comment: @Den: This fix should not have an effect on that. It only does something extra when the remove button is clicked. You added the code to the locations part, not the daily deals. Did this not occur without my fix at all?

Comment: Sorry that was something else. I just fixed that. But your fix doesn't work. I added 3, removed 1, it inputed 2 into the db. 1 of them was correct, the second one only inserted 1 column. No idea why

Comment: Also note that when i put 3 in without touching the remove button. It enters into the databse perfectly. The first 2 are the ones the messed up. The second 2 are without touching the remove button. http://i.imgur.com/OBXfw.png

Comment: I added it to dailydeals. Didn't fix it.

Comment: @Den: It looks like that after removing, the hidden inputs have stale names such as `name[1][2]` while the `1` should have been decremented as well I guess. See my edit.

Comment: I placed that before the $tr.remove() and it did not work. Was that the correct place to put it?

Comment: So, edited code above followed by tr.remove followed by the splice code?

Comment: @Den: Sorry, use `index - 1`. The table header should not count. But I'm also getting an error that `dailydeal` is not defined.

Comment: Doing the -1 seems to fix it! Thanks! It seems to make the page scroll to the top everytime i remove something. What's causing that?

Comment: @Den: That's the error for me. Capitalize `dailydeal` as appropriate.